# Associative PHP Array with Key and Value in PHP Form

Tags: php, arrays

If I have a form:

```
 <form action="/page.php" method="POST">
 <input name="length[<?=$ID;?>]['00:12:00']">
 </form>
```

So, on the BACK end, I clearly have an array, but I need to reference the ID number above, i.e.

```
 foreach($_POST['length'] AS $p) {

 echo($p['ID']);  
 echo($p['ID']['length_number']);


 }
```

Is there a way to structure the front end form input data differently so it is easier to comb through on the back end?

Answer (score 0):

You could reference it by using a hidden input field to grab the ID.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['length'] AS $id=>$values) {
   echo $id;
   print_r($values);
}
```

The the above $values will be an array such as array('00:12:00'=>'{value of the input field}')